# MassTransit3 how to make request from consumer

Tags: masstransit

I want to make a req/res request from `IConsumer.Consume()` method, but I don't see any method on `ConsumeContext<>` that returns a reference to `IRequestClient<,>`. Do I need to hold a reference to `IBusControl` somewhere and use it or I can use context somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it is best to create the request client outside of the consumer and pass it as a dependency to the consumer as an `IRequestClient<,>` interface. The request client is created with `IBus`, which is outside of the consumer context.

It also ensures that the request will be less likely to deadlock with the broker because responses are received on the bus endpoint, and not the receive endpoint of the consumer (which, if you had a concurrency limit of 1, would never finish).

It's also not possible to connect consumers to a started receive endpoint, which is a requirement of the request/response handling (it happens under the covers). The bus, however, can connect consumers for messages which are sent (responses are sent to the bus address, versus being published) which is why it is used for responses to the requests.

To keep message tracking continuous, it may be nice to set the `InitiatorId`  on the outbound request to the `CorrelationId` of the consumer message, as well as copying the `ConversationId`. This helps with tracing and keeping track of the overall message command/event flow.

Comment: Is there any sample code to show how to do this - specifically how to configure a consumer that requires an `IRequestClient`?  My understanding was that I can only configure a consumer by using `ReceiveEndpoint` in the bus configuration - at which time I don't have access to the `bus` instance which I would need to create the request client I want to inject in to my consumer.